# Export const as super type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
import { Observer, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const stdout$ = new Subject<string>();

stdout$
.pipe( /* etc */ )
.subscribe( s => { process.stdout.write( s ); } );

export { stdout$ as Observer<string> }; // ?
```

`Subject` extends `Observer`.  `stdout$` is a `Subject`, but that's an implementation detail I don't want to expose.  I want to export `stdout$`, but I only want to expose `Observer` functionality, without exposing the additional methods of `Subject` (unless they cast; I'm not worried about that).

The best I can think to do is to declare two references to it with different names, and only export one. E.g.,

```
const _stdout$ = new Subject<string>();

_stdout$
.pipe( /* etc */ )
.subscribe( s => { process.stdout.write( s ); } );

export const stdout$: Observer<string> = _stdout$;
```

Is there a way to do it without aliasing it?  Maybe with a JSDoc annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change the type in an export statement.

```
export { variable as reNamed }
```

would only rename the exported variable and not actualy cast.

> but that's an implementation detail I don't want to expose

Your approach with the second exported (public) variable can be used to hide the (private) unexported subject.